# How can I make the pink part of this texure glow?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, eevee-render-engine

This is a wave texture, I don't know how to make the pink part glow, so any help is appreciated!

[image: Wave]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy - Since the other "color" in your image is black, all you have to do is connect it to the *Emission* input of the Principled BSDF. You'll probably want to increase the strength a bit as well (underneath). Don't forget to turn on *Bloom* in the Render Properties tab to make it glow properly:

[image: Glow]